# how to assign group with next expression in regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to catch hole text book into csv format, I am using regex. But I don't really get it right.
I need to search like in this exemple :

```
agur, pi. aguren, subs., lune, mois. Ex.: arbd uaguren, quatre mois.
```

transform it to:

```
col1 = agur
col2 = aguren                        (criteria : after 'pi.' -> col2)
col3 = lune, mois                    (criteria : after 'subs.' -> col3)
col4 = arbd uaguren, quatre mois.    (criteria : after 'Ex.' -> col4)
```

Comment: I think you are better of with creating a dictionary and seraching for words.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where do you stumble?

Comment: There is a `,` after `subs.`, but it's not on your expected output. Is it a typo?

Comment: Could you also accept my answer ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution with a regex for every column:

**col1 = agur**

```
start: beginning of text
stop : ", pi"
regex: ^(.+), pi
```

**col2 = aguren**

```
start: "pi."
stop : ","
regex: .+pi\.([^,]+)
```

**col3 = lune, mois**

```
start: "subs., "
stop : ","
regex: .+subs\., ([^.]+)
```

**col4 = arbd uaguren, quatre mois.**

```
start: "Ex."
stop : end of line
regex: .+Ex\.(.+)
```

For every regex I provided the start and stop criteria. Probably you need to adjust them once you work with real data.